# Why are immutable types passed by copying?

Tags: julia

In the documentation on [types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.1/manual/types/), it says:

> An object with an immutable type is passed around (both in assignment statements and in function calls) by copying, whereas a mutable type is passed around by reference.

What's the purpose of copying an entire object when the object can't be changed? Why not just copy the reference?

Also, when I try to test this with

```
struct Foo
    bar::Int
end

x = Foo(10)
y = x

pointer_from_objref(x) # Ptr{Void} @0x00000001141ea760

pointer_from_objref(y) # Ptr{Void} @0x00000001141ea760
```

it suggest that the objects are the same. Am I misunderstanding this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That documentation appears to have [changed](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/) in more recent versions, to say that immutable objects *may* be copied freely instead of asserting that they will always be copied. (I'm no Julia expert, but the old version sounds fishy.)

Comment: Doh! Should've been on the latest version. So the "may be" indicates that the compiler might optimize by copying the object and the 0.6.1 version had a typo.

Answer (score 0):

pointer_from_objref does not work as you think on immutable types. The results depends on the context you call it from.

Try something like

```
function test(x) return pointer_from_objref(x) end
println(test(x))
println(test(y))
```

I'm actually quite surprised that it even worked, considering that [the source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/665b1def2710f1f5d956b47c670034be0600ebb1/base/pointer.jl#L142) tries to trow an error for immutable arguments.

For your really small immutable, a copy (or just keeping the value in a registrer) is actually much cheaper than going the detour of a pointer (A pointer is the same size as an int and obviously also needs to be copied to a function call).